# How can I send data using xmpppy?

Tags: python, xmpp, xmpppy

How can I send data with xmpppy using this method: http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0047.html#send

I suppose I should use IBB class but have no idea how to do it.   http://xmpppy.sourceforge.net/apidocs/

Comment: No, it is not standard message it is data, that should be sent by another way. http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0047.html#send

Comment: can you describe what your goal is in a broader sense?

Comment: I have cleared up your question - the base64 is beside the point

Comment: Note: question is not a duplicate since this is about data transfer

Comment: free to edit your question and write down what you have found out so far, it makes it more likely for people to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you're on GoogleTalk, ensure that the sender is on the receiver's roster.  Next, on the sender side:

```
from xmpp import *
cl=Client('example.com')
cl.connect()
cl.auth('sender', 'sender_pass')
ibb = filetransfer.IBB()
ibb.PlugIn(cl)

f = open('/tmp/foo')
ibb.OpenStream('123', 'receiver@example.com/resource', f)
```

It doesn't matter what the stream ID is if you're not doing [XEP-95](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0095.html)/[XEP-96](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0096.html) correctly first.

Comment: What should I do if I don't want to send data from file? If it is just set of numbers or string? Should I write them to the file first or there is another way?

Answer (score 0):

I think something like that:

```
import StringIO
...
output = StringIO.StringIO()
output.write('String data')
output.close()


client.OpenStream('123', 'receiver@example.com/resource', output)
```